# PHP Array Re-Arrange

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have some issue to re-arrange array in php. This is what i have...

```
Array
(
    [N] => Array
        (
            [68] => sssssss ttttttt
            [69] => uuuuuu vvvvvvvv
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [05] => zzzzzzzz zzzzzzzz
            [07] => tttttttttttt ttttttttttt
        )

    [P] => Array
        (
            [88] => yyyyyyy zzzzzzzz
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [04] => wwwwww wwwwwww
            [06] => iiiiiii iiiiiiii
            [41] => zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz
        )

)
```

What I want is the following...

```
Array
(
    [N] => Array
        (
            [68] => sssssss ttttttt
            [69] => uuuuuu vvvvvvvv
            // only C are added here with N
            [04] => wwwwww wwwwwww
            [06] => iiiiiii iiiiiiii
            [41] => zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz

        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [05] => zzzzzzzz zzzzzzzz
            [07] => tttttttttttt ttttttttttt
        )

    [P] => Array
        (
            [88] => yyyyyyy zzzzzzzz
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [04] => wwwwww wwwwwww
            [06] => iiiiiii iiiiiiii
            [41] => zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz
        )
)
```

I need the C-Element to be added to N, while all the remaining stay as they are, including the C itself.

How do I accomplish that?

Someone help please...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward stuff; just add the two arrays together like this:

```
// add C to N
$arr['N'] += $arr['C'];
```

If you don't know what the key names are and you just want to target the first and last item:

```
reset($arr); $first = key($arr);
end($arr); $last = key($arr);

$arr[$first] += $arr[$last];
```

Comment: It is not really problem, but what it output is just the first-array added together N+C...but not loop through it...any way i learn some thing from your code...Thanks.

Comment: @MrInternet I'm afraid I don't follow; `print_r($arr)` should give exactly what you want as can be seen [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HfZvhb).

Comment: No really, print_r gives only the sum of $arr['N'] += $arr['C']; But what about the others? like ['D'] ['P']? they are not included.

Comment: @MrInternet Wait, did you do `print_r($arr['N'] += $arr['C']);`? Check the earlier [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HfZvhb) link I sent you.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple.  All you need to do is loop through the last array and add those key value pairs to the first.
Here you go:

```
    //---- $mainArray is your array.


foreach ($mainArray['C'] as $key => $value)
{
      $mainArray['N'][$key] = $value;
}

print_r($mainArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$last_array = $main_array[count($main_array) - 1];
$new_array = array_merge($main_array[0], $last_array);
array_shift($main_array);
array_unshift($main_array, $new_array);
var_dump($main_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, and put my code in very clear format, But unfortunately the code above seems not working, No out put (empty),  but i am trying in different approach, may be some other idea?

Comment: array (size=4)
  0 => null
  'D' => 
    array (size=2)
      16 => string 'BENCHABLA BENCHABLA' (length=19)
      17 => string 'BOULOUDINATS BOULOUDINATS' (length=25)
  'P' => 
    array (size=1)
      14 => string 'AGAR AGAR' (length=9)
  'C' => 
    array (size=1)
      13 => string 'ACHAR Sababa' (length=12)

Comment: The only problem I'm still having is the merge is resetting the key values.  Is that an issue?

Comment: yes, I think so....I mean merge doesn't seems working, as you see the output i post...the first value [0] become Null...some other way please? I am trying too here..

Comment: by the way, to get the last array key we can use this $last_array = end($main_array);

Comment: Finally because of your help, I solve the problem...Thanks Mr.Searsaw. I have posted the answer..